# Incorrect Difference in dates in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android and trying to practice by making small codes.
I am trying to get difference in dates and show text views based on it.
But I am gettting different difference on same day on my Android Phone.
like when I open app, it says difference in days is 5.
I close it, re open it, now it says diff is 4 !

On emulator it is working fine.
I am using following code.
Can anyone pls suggest some improvement ?

```
package com.practice.tablet;



import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TabletsSchedule extends Activity {
    public TextView tvToday;
    public TextView tvMedStartDate;
         public TextView tvMessage;
    public TextView tvDiffInDays;
    public static final String LOGGER = "ADITYA";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tvToday=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tvMedStartDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView001);
        tvMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
        tvDiffInDays=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView06);

        String[] months = {"January", "February",
                "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        int day= today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month=today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year=today.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        String strMonth = months[month];
        Log.d(LOGGER, "displaying today");

        tvToday.setText("Today is "+day+" "+strMonth+" "+year);

        Calendar medStartDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
     //DOB.set(year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth);

        medStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
        medStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
        medStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);

        int day1= medStartDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month1=medStartDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year1=medStartDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

       String strMonth1 = months[month1];
        //String med = medStartDate.toString().toString();

       tvMedStartDate.setText("Medicine Start Date is "+day1+" "+strMonth1+" "+year1);

        long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - medStartDate.getTimeInMillis();

        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 

        tvDiffInDays.setText("Difference in days is "+days);
        Log.d(LOGGER, "days is "+days);

        if (days%2!=0){

                        tvMessage.setText("Today you have to take two tablets");

        }
        if (days%2==0){

                        tvMessage.setText("Today you have to take one tablet");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
...
Calendar medStartDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 

medStartDate.clear();

medStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
medStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
medStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);

...
```

Also you should store important values of `today` object somewhere(Ex.day,month,year etc.) and also should clear it likewise. after that,you can put those values back and then finally you can use it to compare with `medStartDate`.it will avoid the problem you are getting because of tiny different of time.

Comment: Thanks Hiral ! I modified code to clear med start date and now it seems to work as expected. I was very surprised that how its behaving weird ! But all ok now :)

Comment: It is because it also counts tiny difference of time into its long value of milliseconds. Clearing both the calendar objects before setting required value to them and comparing them,would set default values to both of them making both similar initially.so after you set specific values to them,it will ACTUALLY compare them.

Comment: @Hiral plz help me to find out difference between two dates i calculated but that shows some variation to actuval days....plz...

Comment: @Hiral ur post of answer doesn't show the correct values of difference between the two dates.. plz reply me...help..me..

Comment: can you give me example what problem do you get for the correctness of the number of days?